# how to transform xpath expression to xsl key?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm stuck with what should be a simple problem with XSLT keys.

If it is relevant, I'm forced into an XSLT 1.0 parser.

Sample XML:

```
<updates>
  <update>
    <id>first</id>
    <pkglist>
      <collection arch='i686'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.0'/>
      </collection>
      <collection arch='x86_64'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.0'/>
      </collection>
    </pkglist>
  </update>
  <update>
    <id>second</id>
    <pkglist>
      <collection arch='i686'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.1'/>
        <package name='conf' version='1.1'/>
      </collection>
      <collection arch='x86_64'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.2'/>
        <package name='conf' version='1.1'/>
      </collection>
    </pkglist>
  </update>
  <update>
    <id>third</id>
    <pkglist>
      <collection arch='i686'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.3'/>
        <package name='conf' version='1.1'/>
        <package name='src' version='1.3'/>
      </collection>
      <collection arch='x86_64'>
        <package name='bin' version='1.3'/>
        <package name='conf' version='1.2'/>
        <package name='src' version='1.3'/>
      </collection>
    </pkglist>
  </update>
</updates>
```

This XPATH selects what I'm looking for

```
/updates//update[pkglist/collection/package/@name = 'bin']/id/text()
```

I'm looking for all 'id' values in the whole document that have packages with an attribute of 'name'.  But in the real world I have way more packages than would be sensible to list out by hand.

So I figured a key would be the way to go

```
<xsl:key name="idByPackage" match="/updates//update/pkglist/collection/package/@name" use="../../../../id" />
```

But that doesn't give me back anything useful

```
<xsl:key name="idByPackage" match="/updates//update/pkglist/collection/package/@name" use="../../../../id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="updates/update" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="update">
    Updates:
    <xsl:value-of select="id" />
    Related updates
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pkglist" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="pkglist">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('idByPackage', collection/package/@name)">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="collection/package/@name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I know I'm in the right area as when I change the key to this:

```
<xsl:key name="idByPackage" match="/updates//update/pkglist/collection/package/@name" use="../../../../pkglist/collection/package/@name" />
```

The same xsl template spits pack my package names.

When I run the template with the 'looks valid to me but does not work' key I get this:

```
Updates:
first
Related updates
Updates:
second
Related updates
Updates: third
Related updates
```

When I expect to get something like

```
Updates:
first
Related updates
second
third
Updates:
second
Related updates
first
third
Updates: third
Related updates 
first
second
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you want to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the key you need:

```
<xsl:key name="idByPackage" 
         match="update/id" use="../pkglist/collection/package/@name" />
```

When this XSLT is run on your sample input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="idByPackage"
           match="update/id" use="../pkglist/collection/package/@name" />
  <xsl:variable name="nl" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="updates/update" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="update">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Updates:', $nl, 
                                 id, $nl, 
                                 'Related updates:', $nl)" />

    <xsl:variable name="name" select="pkglist/collection/package/@name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('idByPackage', $name)[. != current()/id]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $nl)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
Updates:
first
Related updates:
second
third
Updates:
second
Related updates:
first
third
Updates:
third
Related updates:
first
second
```